# Frontrunning Uniswap horror story transactions

Tags: security, attacks, uniswap, frontrunning

From the [Ethereum is a Dark Forest](https://medium.com/@danrobinson/ethereum-is-a-dark-forest-ecc5f0505dff) post, the rescue plan was:

1. Deploy a Getter contract which, when called by its owner, would make
   the burn call ONLY if activated, and otherwise revert.
2. Deploy a Setter contract which, when called by its owner, would
   activate the Getter contract.
3. Submit the set transaction and the get transaction in the same
   block.

But a key detail is missing to study the incident and when the frontrunning succeeded.

**What are the transaction hashes of the rescue team and the frontrunner?**